# Native C++ SplitterBar glitches

Tags: c++, windows

I made a splitter bar successfully; however, the splitter bar glitches when I move the cursor fast. It looks similar to the Visual Studio 2010 splitter bar. The Visual Studio splitter bar doesn't glitch at all when the cursor is moved fast. I assume they are using the PatBlt just like I am. The splitter bar is being processed through the following messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONUP. This happens to ever splitter bar I've encountered besides the one in visual studio. How the heck are they doing it? Here is an example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3509/Splitter-Window-Tutorial This is not mine but is does the  same thing. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Arx, it's a duplicate. But, I have my own solution using GDI instead of WPF for anyone interested. Takes a bit of code to implement, but it's worth it, especially when your building a framework.

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11290902/292432) to the question I linked to is simple and doesn't use WPF.

Comment: My solution seems to do the job very well. Only uses a solid-brush w/ PatBlt.