# WCF Attach to process in visual studio

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I would like to try attach to my WCF process. I have installed remote debugger for VS2017, I can connect and i see my w3wp process but when I try to attach I have this error:

[image: Remote debugger]

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: have you been through this entire page, and read every single detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017#network-configuration and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2017

Comment: Based on the error messages warnings, you'd better to check that whether it is related to your firewall. For example, please make sure devenv.exe is in the firewall program exceptions list, and with the domain checkbox checked. Or you could disable/close it in your local machine, test it again. Of course, you can see [Set Up the Remote Tools on the Device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.120).aspx) for instructions about how to configure the firewall for local debugging.

Comment: Again, you can check if following thread helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923400/configure-visual-studio-2010-remote-debugger and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/a-dcom-error-occurred-trying-to-contact-the-remote-computer-access-is-denied?view=vs-2017